# Windows Metro Apps lauch executable

Tags: windows, modern-ui

When launching a Windows 10 App from the *.exe (explorer or command line)
generally located in "Program Files\WindowsApps\"
Windows gave some errors for files not found:

```
MSVCP140_APP.dll
VCRUNTIME140_APP.dll
SharedLibrary.dll
```

and others (depends on the App you are launching)

The App works fine if you lanch it via the start menu...

Anybody knows how to launch this Apps from command line
(without the shell:appsfolder solution)
launching the App .exe...

Comment: That’s most likely not possible. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

That's by design.

Apps in Program Files\WindowsApps is are modern apps. It's different from classic win32 type application.

You can launch it via command with this syntax:

```
explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\*PackageFamilyName* ! *<APPLICATION ID>*
```

<sub>[source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/starting-windows-10-store-app-from-the-command/836354c5-b5af-4d6c-b414-80e40ed14675)</sub>

Comment: without using shell:appsfolder...